# Getting author page slug from get_users() or get_userdata() functions

Tags: users, author, slug

`wp_list_authors()` gives a list of author pages permalinks (site.com/author/john, site.com/author/jenny, etc). I want the same links using `get_users()` or `get_userdata()` functions instead. I need these functions because I display authors in a very customized way. However I don't know how to get proper author page slugs with those functions.

(for example, one author has an email address as her Username, and the `wp_list_authors()`-generated link for her author page has dashes in place of the "@" and the ".". This is to say that the author page slug is not necessarily the same thing as the username)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the author page URL for any user by their user ID using the WordPress native function [`get_author_posts_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url). Combining this with [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to retrieve an array of users, you can create an author list in pretty much any way you like!

Below is an example of the usage of `get_author_posts_url()`, displaying a link to the author page for the currently logged in user:

```
$userid = get_current_user_id();
echo '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url( $userid ) . '">' . __( 'User profile', 'my_textdomain' ) . '</a>';
```